Subscription feature of an app using Google Pay - Unable to test Free Trial
I am building an app which includes a subscription feature with a 3 day free trial and a monthly renewal subscription. I am using Google Pay as the payment gateway for my app. During my testing, I found that the user once signedup (Using email: abc@gmail.com) and subscribed to free trial from the app. I then sign out of the app and signedup again using a different email (xyz@gmail.com), unfortunately the GPay subscription is showing a message "You are not eligible for the free trial". I am not sure why it is showing this error message.
Here are the steps for my testing:

My Google Play store is linked to my personal email: sri@gmail.com
I downloaded my project app and installed it.
I tried to sign up for a subscription feature with test email abc@gmail.com, and then successfully enrolled for the free trial period.
Now, I logout of the app and tried to sign up with another email xyz@gmail.com in the android app and went to the subscription page. It then shows the error "You are not eligible for free trial". (Attached Image)
enter image description here

I am not sure what is the reason behind this issue. Can someone help me understand or sort out this issue?
I tried to search some forums could find the correct solution.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a question for Google's support.
